# Angular code failed to compile

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to angular and tried below code by following a tutorial to run few lines of code and it showed me this error.

> `Failed to compile.  C:/my-app/src/app/app.component.ts (3,35): File
>   'C:/my-app/src/app/app.service.ts' is not a module.`

#### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { HackerNewsService } from './app.service'; 
@Component({ selector: 'hacker-component', templateUrl: './app.component.html', styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] }) 
export class HackerNewsComponent { 
    news = {}; 
    constructor(private HackerNewsService: HackerNewsService) {     
        this.HackerNewsService.getNews().subscribe(data => this.news = data); 
    } 
}
```

#### app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'; 
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; 
@Injectable() export class HackerNewsService { 
    constructor ( private http: Http ) {} 
    getNews() { 
        return this.http.get(https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?q‌​uery=nodejs&tags=sto‌​ry) .map((res:Response) => res.json()); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Well, it is very difficult to help you without seeing your code

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Comment: here is my code

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { HackerNewsService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'hacker-component',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class HackerNewsComponent {
  news = {};
  constructor(private HackerNewsService: HackerNewsService) {
    this.HackerNewsService.getNews().subscribe(data => this.news = data);
  }
}

Comment: i don't know how to indent my code but the above is the app.component.ts

Comment: below is the app.service.ts

Comment: <code> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HackerNewsService {
  constructor (
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  getNews() {
    return this.http.get(`https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?query=nodejs&tags=story`)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}</code>

Comment: Your code from the comments was added to the post. In the future, please edit your post to add such context.

Answer (score 0):

this HackerNewsService  needs to be in providers in AppModule. like this sample

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DefaultComponent } from './admin/default/default.component';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { TimeComponent } from './time/time.component';
import { TimeService } from './time/time.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    DefaultComponent,
    TimeComponent,
    InputMaskDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    TimeService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: oh please i get it but i'm confused. i'm new to it.. can you help me explain thank you.